# How to use sudo to delete the contents of a directory

Tags: shell, centos, sudo

I have a legitimate need to empty a directory to which my account does not have access (it is a cache directory used by an application, and is owned by the account that runs the application.)  My account has full `sudo` privileges (I think), but I can't figure out how to delete the contents of the directory in question.  My account can't `cd` into the directory, only into the parent directory.

```
sudo rm directory/*
```

gives the response

```
cannot remove `directory/*': no such file or directory
```

This seems like a problem that should have a simple answer, but I can't find it.

**Edit:** The directory in question is definitely not empty:

```
sudo ls directory/
```

returns over 1000 filenames.

Comment: Give us the output of `ls directory/*`. From what I see here, your directory is empty already.

Comment: It seems to be. I almost left an answer with rm -rf. >_> But now that I think about it, the wildcard isn't expanding.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're having problems because your shell is trying to expand `*` into the list of files, but it can't since you don't have rights to read the directory.

I can think of two things that would work

```
sudo bash -c "rm directory/*"
```

In this case, the * isn't expanded by you, but by root, who can read the directory

OR

```
sudo find directory -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

The above will only delete files, not directories (otherwise it would delete `directory` along with it's contents), but feels less error prone to me.

Edit: In the first option, I had accidentally written directory.* instead of directory/*

Comment: Yes. Nearly left an answer with rm -rf before reading xD

Comment: The second option worked for me.  Turned out I had set up sudo more carefully than I remembered, so 'sudo bash' is disallowed.  Could you explain the syntax of the second option?  I understand it as far as 'rm', but what do the braces, the slash and the semi-colon do?

Comment: find command has a handy `-delete` option.

Comment: Find runs the command in -exec once for each match it finds, and it replaces {} with the name of the file it found. `\;` is just the way you end a `-exec` command with find. As Fabrizio just pointed out, there's a -delete option for find, so the command can be simplified to `sudo find directory -type f -delete`

Answer (score -1):

**Any** time you are going to `sudo rm` things, you should gravely consider what you are doing if you are not using explicit paths.

`sudo rm /explicit/path/to/directory/*` should work.  You will still get that error if there are not files in `directory`; you can suppress that with `rm -f` (**not** `rm -fr` unless you are *absolutely* certain of what you are doing).